# Image floated left with fluid measure

Tags: html, css, layout

I have blocks of content like this

```
<div>
    <img src="/path/to/image.jpg">
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <div>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Please check jsFiddle for a complete example with CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/Simo990/fqHGn/1/).

No one of these elements should have a fixed width or height. As you can see in the jsFiddle, I have used `float:left` (130px) on the image and `margin-left` (140px) on the other elements, in order to align them correctly.

My problem is that I have lots of images with a **variable width**. I just can't change the margin every time I have a new image. I want the other elements (`h4` and `div`) to be able to dinamically adapt to the remaining width:

[image]
[image]

How can I achieve this?

Please help, I am really stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a CSS solution by myself:

just add a `margin-right` to the image.

Works well even in IE!